# What is the significance in the fact that the ratio between the height of an optimal square based pyramid and the sidelength of the square is root 2

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, volume

If you optimize a right square pyramid, the ratio of the height and the sidelength of the square will be root 2. Why is this? I feel that it could be because the diagonal of a square with sidelength 1 is root 2 but how does that exactly explain this.

Also its interesting because you'd think an optimal pyramid would try to mimic a sphere or a cube or a cylinder where the ratio of the height and the sidelength/diameter is 1:1, but it doesn't.....

Comment: What does "optimize" mean in this context? And what is a "right" square pyramid?

Comment: Considering the optimal pyramid as having equal their four dihedral angles in the base, this means simply that this dihedral angle is $\arctan^{-1}(\sqrt2)=54^{\circ}73561032$.

Comment: a right pyramid is a pyramid where the base is a regular polygon and the apex is at the center of that polygon

Comment: @Piquito interesting that you made that connection, however tan inverse takes the ratio of the height and 1/2 of the base length. I'm talking about  height and base length

Answer (score 0):

> I do not exactly know what you mean in your question. But I made a answer that is too long for a comment.

---

Well, the volume of a [square pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramid) is [given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramid#General_square_pyramid) by:

$$\mathcal{V}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\text{H}\cdot\text{L}^2\tag1$$

Where the base length is given by $\text{L}$ and perpendicular height is given by $\text{H}$.

A right square pyramid with base length $\text{L}$ and perpendicular height $\text{H}$ has [surface area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramid#Right_square_pyramid) of:

$$\mathcal{A}=\text{L}^2+\text{L}\cdot\sqrt{\text{L}^2+\left(2\cdot\text{H}\right)^2}\tag2$$

With a given volume we can solve equation $(1)$ for $\text{H}$:

$$\mathcal{V}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\text{H}\cdot\text{L}^2\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{H}=\frac{\mathcal{V}}{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\text{L}^2}=\frac{3\cdot\mathcal{V}}{\text{L}^2}\tag3$$

Substitute equation $(3)$ into equation $(2)$ gives:

$$\mathcal{A}=\text{L}^2+\text{L}\cdot\sqrt{\text{L}^2+\left(2\cdot\frac{3\cdot\mathcal{V}}{\text{L}^2}\right)^2}\tag4$$

Now, we need to solve:

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{A}}{\partial\text{L}}=0\tag5$$

And it gives:

$$\text{L}^5\cdot\left(\text{L}+\sqrt{\text{L}^2+\frac{36\cdot\mathcal{V}^2}{\text{L}^4}}\right)-18\cdot\mathcal{V}^2=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{L}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{\mathcal{V}}}{\sqrt[6]{2}}\tag6$$

Solving for $\text{H}$, gives:

$$\mathcal{V}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\text{H}\cdot\text{L}^2\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{H}=\sqrt[6]{2}\cdot3^\frac{2}{3}\cdot\mathcal{V}^\frac{2}{3}\tag7$$

So, the fraction is:

$$\frac{\text{H}}{\text{L}}=\frac{\sqrt[6]{2}\cdot3^\frac{2}{3}\cdot\mathcal{V}^\frac{2}{3}}{\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{\mathcal{V}}}{\sqrt[6]{2}}\right)}=6^\frac{1}{3}\cdot\mathcal{V}^\frac{1}{3}\tag8$$